# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras' error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting this error when using the code below:

```
 "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'".  My tensorflow 2.0 version is 2.15.0.
```

I have tried to install keras in my kernal environment but still get the same error.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
input_size = 2
output_size = 1

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                            tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size)
                            ])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(training_data['inputs'], training_data['targets'], epochs=100, verbose=0)
```

Comment: What is the output of `pip install keras`? Is it already installed?

Comment: What are the version of python and keras? When installing TF with pip or conda, the right version of keras is also installed.

Comment: The error "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'" indicates that there is an issue with your TensorFlow installation or environment setup. In TensorFlow 2.x, the keras module is integrated directly into the TensorFlow package, so you should import it directly from tensorflow instead of separately importing keras.